# Initialize different dependencies based on compile time flag?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, guice, dagger-2

I'm writing a java service which requires a different set of dependencies to be initialized for different companies.

To simplify the problem let's say that this service uses a `JuiceMaker` interface where there are `CompanyAJuiceMaker` and `CompanyBJuiceMaker` implementing classes. When I ship my software to company A I’d like my service to be initialized with `CompanyAJuiceMaker` and when I ship it to company B I’d like it to be initialized with `CompanyBJuiceMaker`

I understand that the easiest way to do this is to just have different git branches per company. The problem with this solution is that it requires a code change everytime we sell to a different company.

On the other hand, a solution that determines the beans to initialize at runtime would require whoever starts the software(most likely our customer) to specify the kinds of dependencies they want to use. We feel that this is unnecessary complexity for them and also giving them too much power over what version of the software they can use.

Is there a solution that allows me to specify which beans to initialize at build time? Preferably I can compile the code with an argument specifying which set of beans I want to initialize(any compiler and DI framework is fine if it can achieve this)

Jessica

Comment: Lots of details are missing, so I give just a general new option.
you can put all your dependencies as a separate jar(service-core.jar, service-implA.jar, service-implB.jar), and on runtime, this will be the one on the machine JRE runtime.
if you want to automate that, you can write a script to run after compile and "package" by the flag.
another option in DI you can load a file with DI you want from path instead of resource and put it after compiling by script.
also, you may want to look at this:
https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/

Comment: This is _exactly_ the kind of scenario that Spring Boot auto-configuration is made for. You simply include different sets of modules with your runtime deployment.